# running multiple sessions in android

Tags: android, session

I am learning Android and I have written some simple apps which work.  The apps individually are quite simple. But I want to execute these as asynchronous functions in the background without using intervention at regular intervals.  For example, this is the sequence of methods I want to execute every 15 minutes:

1. Check for internet connectivity
2. Try to access www.google.com and return success or failure
3. Try to access a bad URL so you get a failure
4. Send SMS in background check for success or failure
5. Send gmail in background check for success or failure
6. Send yahoo mail in background check for success or failure

I can create a method for each of the items.  The question is how do I execute each of these one after another and get the result to log? Then repeat the whole process.  Do I need to sleep() between each of these activity?

I can do this in iOS Swift using NSURLSession.

Appreciate your help and guidance on this.

Comment: "Do I need to sleep() between each of these activity?" -- please no. Use `JobScheduler`, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher. Use `AlarmManager` (or [Evernote's `android-job` library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)) if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21.

Comment: use Services to run background process.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Looks like I can use Job Scheduler and Services for my problem.  Is it possible to trigger the job scheduler based on GPS updates? if so can you point me to an example?  thanks